# Export a huge django queryset in CSV format with rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create an endpoint that exports user information as a CSV file.

The queryset I'm attempting to export contains more than 250,000 users.

But, this method takes too much time and causes the server to timeout.

In my existing code, I create the CSV file on my server and write the queryset content to it.

```py
for idx, user in enumerate(queryset):
    print('{}/{}'.format(idx+1, total))
    row = [user.first_name, user.last_name, user.email]
    # some logic
    if user.is_vip():
    # .....
    if user.profile and user.profile.phone:
    # .....
    csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Once the loop is complete I send the file:

```py
file = open('export_users.csv', 'rb')
response = FileResponse(file, content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Length'] = os.fstat(file.fileno()).st_size
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % '{}_export_users.csv'.format(date_now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d:%M:%S'))
return response
```

How can I generate the CSV file and send the response faster so that it doesn't cause a timeout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the response much faster by streaming the content, writing each row to the user as it's generated.

Django has documentation to help with this exact problem:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/outputting-csv/#streaming-large-csv-files

```py
import csv

from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse


class Echo:
    def write(self, value):
        return value


def streaming_csv_view(request):
    queryset = User.objects.values_list("first_name", "last_name", "email")
    echo_buffer = Echo()
    csv_writer = csv.writer(echo_buffer)

    # By using a generator expression to write each row in the queryset
    # python calculates each row as needed, rather than all at once.
    # Note that the generator uses parentheses, instead of square
    # brackets – ( ) instead of [ ].
    rows = (csv_writer.writerow(row) for row in queryset)

    response = StreamingHttpResponse(rows, content_type="text/csv")
    response["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="users.csv"'
    return response
```

For more information on the differences between generator expressions and list comprehensions, this python howto is a good resource:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions

Here's the important part:

> With a list comprehension, you get back a Python list; ...a list containing the resulting lines, not an iterator. **Generator expressions return an iterator that computes the values as necessary, not needing to materialize all the values at once.**

To optimize your query, use a `values_list` query instead of calling `all()`. With a `values_list` query, you can still fetch fields through relationships. For example:

```py
User.objects.values_list(
    "first_name",
    "last_name",
    "email",
    "profile__phone",  # get the profile.phone value
)
```

Comment: This solution avoided the timeout, I just didn't understand how the generator expression worked with the StreamingHttpResponse. Thank you.
But it still takes 10min to loop over all my users. Is there a way to reduce it? USing threads maybe?

Comment: @JérémyOcteau I don't think there's a way to thread this or make it parallel. Is your queryset optimized? Use a `values_list` query like the one in my example. Testing locally with 250K users, using a `values_list` query is 90% **faster** than using `all()`. Also look at [django's optimization docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/performance/) for more ideas.

Comment: the thing is I'm using many relationships when exporting my users. I edited the question so you can see what I do.

Comment: @JérémyOcteau I've added more to my answer.

Comment: But when I use the "profile__phone", I will get the ID of the Object Phone. How can I modify that?
The object Phone contains an Object Country (to know the code to use +1, +33....) and a Charfield.

Comment: Also I have a One to Many relationship between a User and multiple Subscriptions. 
I want the most recent subscription. Can I achieve that with values_list() ?

Comment: @JérémyOcteau Since these last couple things are outside of the question's scope, I created an example to answer your questions here: https://gist.github.com/blackrobot/e55369080490eadfda84cee06ec3d0a8